# Is it bad practice to use a single HTML page which replaces the innerHTML of a <div> with many other pages?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a basic API documentation site and have ~20 endpoints in my API. I settled on a single HTML page with a navigation bar on the side displaying subheadings, each with a list containing the relevant endpoints e.g:

```
Home
    About this API

Users
    Get users
    Add users
    Delete users

Products
    ...
```

By default, "about this api" is highlighted and its local HTML page is read in to an empty div to the right of the sidebar.

```
window.onload = function () {

    // Default page
    addContent("content/api/about_api.html", "content");
};

function addContent(page, element) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", page, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

As list elements are clicked, the highlight moves to that option and the same function is called with a new page which is stored as a data attribute in the element.

Everything works fine and is responsive, but i'm wondering if this is bad practice? Would you recommend a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad practice, actually it is quiet common and is called a Single Page Application.

There are some aspects to consider though, like e.g. the accessibility for search engines if you wan't your SPA to be indexed properly. There are lots of articles and tutorial for SPA available though, I'd recommend reading through them.

Answer (score 0):

As an initial response, I would say, it is wrong,

Think of the basics,  html is the skeleton, css is design and js is functionality. you should not try to mix them up. If you don't have a server running than i can see why you chose this method. 
Please read on server side rendering and handlebars, if you get them the question you have will be understood very quickly